# tomato doesn't play well with my xbox360

Tags: xbox360, tomato

i recently changed my router firmware to tomato and now my xbox360 does not seem to be able to stream music, video or pictures from any of my connected computers.
it only sees my main computer and not the others. when i go to play video from the one computer, i can see all the files but it does not allow me to stream.

i am wondering if i need to change something in tomato because the previous  firmware worked without any modification, just plug and play.
thanks for the help

Comment: Have you enabled UPnP?

Comment: Is your Xbox connected via wireless or via a wire? There may be a setting that wireless machines cannot connect to each other.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make sure that Universal Plug and Play (UPnP) is enabled in the firmware.  You can check this by:

1. Logging into the router
2. Clicking on "Port Forwarding" from the menu on the left
3. Selecting "UPnP" from the sub-men that pops out
4. Check the box labeled "Enabled UPnP"
5. Click "Save" at the bottom of the page

[Here is an example](http://lampiweb.com/virtual/tomato/forward-upnp.htm) of what the page will look like.

Answer (score 0):

no, my xbox is connected via LAN line directly to the router. The xbox sees when my main computer is there but does not let me play anything from it. and where the rest of my computers went, i do not know...